# Examples of a group with infinitely many ends which are not represented as a free product of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$-non-trivial groups.

1. Is it correct that the number of ends of the free product $F_1\ast F_2$ is infinite?

My thoughts about this: Since $e(G)=\infty$ then $G=F_1\ast F_2$, a non-trivial free product using Stalling's theorem. Applying Grushko theorem, $F_1$, $F_2$ are generated by strictly fewer elements. The intersection of $F_1$ with the free subgroup is a free subgroup. So from induction $F_1$ is a free group. The same is true for $F_2$. And $G=F_1 \ast F_2$ is free. Is it correct?

2. If it is true. Is it possible to find examples of groups $G$ with infinitely many ends which are not represented as a free product of groups $G=F_1\ast F_2$?

If you don't mind can you explain this in more details?

Thank you!

Comment: What you have written seems incoherent. Stallings' theorem says that a group has more than one end iff it admits a nontrivial decomposition as an amalgamated free product or as an HNN extension. Note also that $C_2*C_2$ has two ends.

Comment: @Derek Holt thank you! As I understand you that the number of ends of the free product of non-trivial groups may be not equal to $\infty$. When it may be equal to $\infty$? In what cases?

Comment: In general, you should also allow amalgamation/HNN extension over finite subgroups. Then it is a classical result due to Stallings and Bergman.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Thank you! If you don't mind may you advise the reference to the book or to the articles linked to Stallings and Bergman results where it's described? Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups

Comment: @Moishe Kohan thank you for your help and for your time. And last question for more clarity. May you advise an example of the such group with infinitely many ends which are not represented as a free product of non-trivial groups. Thank you very much!

Comment: Amalgamate two groups isomorphic to $S_3$ over order 2 subgroups.

Comment: @UserIn You can take $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, which is isomorphic to the amalgamated free product of two cyclic groups, one of order 6 and one of order 4, over an order 2 cyclic subgroup.

Comment: @Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda thank you for your answer. It's interesting example. If you don't mind may you please explain why this group $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has infinitely many ends $e (\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}))=\infty$.  And Why this group is not represented as a free product of groups? Thank you very much!

Comment: @UserIn The group $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has at least two ends by Stallings' theorem. Since it is not virtually cyclic (exercise: it contains a free subgroup of rank $2$), it does not have $2$ ends, so it has infinitely many ends. If $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ were representable as a free product, then it would have trivial center (exercise); but its center is cyclic of order $2$, consisting of the matrices $\{ I_2, -I_2 \}$.

Comment: But note: to see that a non-trivial amalgamated free product (like $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$) has infinitely many ends is the easy direction of Stallings' theorem; you can do this directly (a proof is sketched on the [Wikipedia page for the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups)).

Comment: @Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda thank you for your help!